# How to call phantomJS in ipython from selenium

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, ipython

I'm trying to use PhantomJS to test a webpage in Python. I installed phantomJS 1.9.7 and I can run the phantomjs console from a terminal correctly. I can also start a phantomJS webdriver session with

```
>phantomjs --webdriver 8910
```

wget can fetch this page:

```
> wget 127.0.0.1:8910
Unknown Command - {"headers":{"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.5","Connection":"keep-alive","DNT":"1","Host":"localhost:8910","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"GET","url":"/","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"","directory":"/","path":"/","relative":"/","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/","queryKey":{},"chunks":[""]}}
```

So I know that the server is up and answering requests. Now, I try to use it from ipython:

```
pip install selenium
```

runs ok. From inside ipython,

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(port=8910)
```

and I get

```
Message: u'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\n<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">\n<TITLE>ERRO: A URL solicitada n&atilde;o pode ser recuperada</TITLE>\n<STYLE type="text/css"><!--BODY{background-color:#ffffff;font-family:verdana,sans-serif}PRE{font-family:sans-serif}--></STYLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>ERRO</H1>\n<H2>A URL solicitada n&atilde;o pode ser recuperada</H2>\n<HR noshade size="1px">\n<P>\n\nNa tentativa de recuperar a URL:\n<A HREF="http://127.0.0.1:8910/wd/hub/session">http://127.0.0.1:8910/wd/hub/session</A>\n<P>\nO seguinte erro foi encontrado:\n\n<UL>\n<LI>\n<STRONG>\nFalha na conex&atilde;o\n</STRONG>\n</UL>\n\n<P>\nO sistema retornou:\n<PRE><I>    (111) Connection refused</I></PRE>\n\n<P>\nO host remoto (servidor) ou a rede pode estar indispon&iacute;vel. Por favor tente novamente.\n</P>'
```

The important part is the "Connection refused". How can I connect the PhantomJS webdriver from ipython?

Comment: Looks like you mixed up your ports. Or is this a typo?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo. Fixed in the post.

Comment: Still looks like a typo. I assume your web server runs on your localhost. You can't run the web server **and** phantomjs server on the same port 8910. Does `wget`-ing your web server work?

Comment: So do I need to start the server or not? Can I just call the webdriver.PhantomJS from inside ipython without starting the phantomjs --webdriver 8910? I tested both and I still get the Connection Denied error.

Comment: I can't find the documentation for `selenium.webdriver.PhantomJS` so I don't really know what port means. You could try the remote webdriver with an already running phantomjs server like in your post: [`selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver).